# MySQL - SELECT AS in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, select

For some reason, this doesn't work:

```
select substring(rating, instr(rating,',') +1, +2) as val
from users where val = '15';
```

It gives this error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'val' in 'where clause'

How do I do it then?

Comment: If you _ever_ find yourself having to process parts of a column, your schema is wrong.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, you cannot use `ALIAS` on the `WHERE` clause. You shoul be using the column,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) AS val 
FROM   users 
WHERE  SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) = '15'
```

The reason is as follows: the order of operation is SQL,

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

the `ALIAS` takes place on the `SELECT` clause which is before the `WHERE` clause.

if you really want to use the alias, wrap it in a subquery,

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) AS val 
        FROM   users
    ) s
WHERE   val  = '15'
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea of the alias was to minimize the select line; a bit strange you cannot do it; But thanks - the above works great.

Comment: The explanation doesn't completely make sense, given that one can use column aliases in `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Answer (score 10):

You sure can with MySQL, please see below, just tested this and it works fine:

```
Select substring(rating, instr(rating,',') +1, +2) as val 
From users 
Having val = '15';
```

You can also do things like "having val is null" etc.

With ALIASes you can't use WHERE, but using HAVING does the trick.

H

Answer (score 4):

`val` is not defined, it's just an alias. Do it like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) AS val 
FROM   users 
WHERE  SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) = 15
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2)
FROM   users 
WHERE  SUBSTRING(rating, INSTR(rating,',') +1, +2) = '15'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem any better than the existing answers.