# rawquery in laravel fails when using select

Tags: sql, laravel

This is my code:

```
public function scopeClosest($query, $lat, $lng)
{
    return $query->selectRaw(
        'Select * , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'
    );

}
```

If I run it I get this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radian' at line 1

If I remove Select*, so it looks like this:

```
return $query->selectRaw(
            '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'
        );
```

no error is produces and I get 5 objects back but they only contain distance like this:

```
  #items: Collection {#377 ▼
    #items: array:5 [▼
      0 => Listing {#378 ▼
        #connection: null
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        #perPage: 15
        +incrementing: true
        +timestamps: true
        #attributes: array:1 [▼
          "distance" => 5511.8536628578
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but try this:

```
return $query->selectRaw(
    '*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'
);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, I added HAVING distance < 25 to the query:
' AS distance HAVING distance < 25' and now get again You have an error in your SQL syntax. Any idea how to correct this one?

Comment: @Maxlight I am not an mysql expert at all, but I think that you can't use having in a selectRaw. You could use havingRaw.

Comment: did as you recommended and now get: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` having distance < 10) I don't know why but laravel is executing that count query before my actual query where I use distance. Any ideas?

Comment: @Maxlight Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413867/mysql-select-as-in-where