# Why can't I use the alias? using raw LARAVEL

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

The problem is, that the alias `fechas` doesn't take any value... I can't use it

```
>    $tabla_c2 = DB::table('horarios')
>     ->select('id_voluntario',DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%y-%m-%d')as fechas"))
>     ->where('id_voluntario','=', $temp)
>     ->where('fechas','=', $datee)
>     ->get();
```

Comment: This is not a laravel problem, but a SQL limitation. Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413867/mysql-select-as-in-where

Comment: Check [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: Instead of `->where('fechas','=', $datee)` use `->having(''fechas','=', $datee)`

Comment: don't use `having` it is slow and uses more resources. Some read material [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328636/which-sql-statement-is-faster-having-vs-where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is a SQL limitation - **you cannot use an alias for a column in a `where` clause**.

One workaround, as suggested by @ljubadr, is to use `having` instead - although I will side with @Jeffrey on this and say it is going to unnecessarily make your query slower.

Rather than use the alias, you can utilise `whereRaw()`:

```
$tabla_c2 = DB::table('horarios')
 ->select('id_voluntario',DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%y-%m-%d')as fechas"))
 ->where('id_voluntario','=', $temp)
 ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%y-%m-%d') = ?", $datee)
 ->get();
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) under `Eloquent Aggregates`.